# How to export geospatial files from CARTO?

Tags: shapefile, export, carto

I recently made an iso-area trade polygon in Carto from a point and would like to export this area as a shapefile, geopackage, or geojson for stylizing in QGIS. However, when I try to export, there's only an option to export the attribute table as a CSV. Does anyone know if it is possible to export shapefiles in Carto?